# How to Continue data download in other ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

There are several files to download in a particular `viewController`. When a user taps on download of a particular file, a `progressView` appears to show the amount of data downloaded. Also at a particular time multiple files can be downloaded. Since the file is quite large, it takes a few minutes to complete the download. The problem is that when I go to another `ViewController`, all the downloads stop and i have to stay on the download `ViewController` and wait for the download to complete. I am using `NSURLSession` to download data. Is there a way to get the download going even when the download `ViewController` is dismissed?

One option is i will transfer the code to `appDelegate`. Is there any other convenient way to do this task.

Comment: If you need some extra information that i forgot to mention here,please mention that

Comment: The problem is that, you might be using main thread to execute download task, why don't you use asynchronous thread to download the files in background and still send the progress update to UI on main thread?

Comment: But the problem is for each download task,i have made an object that have several flags and properties like downloaded data,progress of progressView etc.....how it can be possible

Answer (score 1):

Try to have a look on AFNetworking
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

You can define this part in Appdelegate but be sure to make them visible ( Properties )

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
```

Then in any view get them and start the download task

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/download.zip"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
    return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
}];
[downloadTask resume];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```